# Ubuntu Bonding /DNS

Tags: dns, bonding

Newbie question.

Setting up bonding on a Ubuntu workstation. Seems to be working accept the DNS settings are not taking. I can ping various IP addresses from within the device, and I'm RDP'd into it without issues.

I'm sure it's an easy fix or I typo'd something

Thanks
Jason

[image: interfaces file]

[image: resov.conf]

[image: nsswitch.conf]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`